# How to set CSS property for focused md-select?

Tags: angular

I tried this property:

```
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-arrow,
.mat-select:focus:not(.mat-select-disabled).mat-primary .mat-select-trigger {
  box-shadow: 0 7px 8px 0 rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.22), 0 5px 22px 4px rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.14), 0 12px 17px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.16);
}
```

It does not work!

I use new Angular 4 and Material

Comment: have you try delete the not（xxx）

Comment: Yes, I treid delete it

Comment: Where are you putting these rules?

Comment: In main.css file that imported to main component